# How to show that the variance of an estimator of a model without intercept is neccessary smaller than the var of one with an intercept

Tags: variance, least-squares

Sorry for the format, I am still not used to writing formulas on this website. But this is the problem I'm trying to figure out.
[image: Set up of the question I'm attempting to solve]

I am attempting to show that the variance of the OLS estimator without the intercept is necessarily $\le$ to the variance of the OLS estimator with the intercept.

$$\text{var}(\tilde\beta)=\frac{\sigma^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \le \text{var}(\hat\beta)=\frac{\sigma^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2}$$

It seems obvious that the denominator on the right is smaller than the one on the left, leading to a smaller $\text{var}(\tilde{\beta})$. However, the professor says I am still missing a big component, but would not explain as to what it is that I'm missing. Is the inequality below not self-evident enough, or must I do something more to prove that $\text{var}(\tilde{\beta})$ is smaller? Sorry for the format. I am still learning to use this website, and I'd appreciate any and all input.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your equations instead of using images. Using images for equations is frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that there are two models:
a) $y=\tilde{X}\beta+\varepsilon,\quad \tilde{X}=(x_1,\dots,x_n)'$
b) $y=X\beta+\varepsilon,\quad X=[1:\tilde{X}]$

In the first model $$\text{Var}(\tilde\beta)=\sigma^2(\tilde{X}'\tilde{X})^{-1}=\dfrac{\sigma^2}{\sum x_i^2}$$

In the second model $$\text{Var}(\hat\beta)=\sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}=\sigma^2\begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{n}+\dfrac{\bar{x}^2}{\sum (x_i-\bar{x})^2}
& \dfrac{-\bar{x}}{\sum (x_i-\bar{x})^2} \\
\dfrac{-\bar{x}}{\sum (x_i-\bar{x})^2} & \dfrac{1}{\sum (x_i-\bar{x})^2} \end{bmatrix}$$
so $\sigma^2(\sum (x_i-\bar{x})^2)^{-1}$ is not $\text{Var}(\hat\beta)$, it is just $\text{Var}(\hat\beta_1)$. You were missing $\hat\beta_0$, which indeed is "a big component", because it is the difference between the two models :)

If you wish to show that $\text{Var}(\tilde\beta) \le \text{Var}(\hat\beta)$ you have to show that
$$a'[\sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}]a-a'\left[\dfrac{\sigma^2}{\sum x_i^2}\right]a  \ge 0\quad\text{for each } a\in\mathbb{R}^n$$

Comment: You can't use the simple model-based formula for $\mathrm{var}[\tilde\beta]$ (unless $\beta_0=0$) because the no-intercept model is misspecified.